# What needs unblocking to allow access to Windows Store/Feedback Hub

Tags: firewall, windows-10, webfilter

I have a domain joined machine that whilst on our company VPN, I am unable to access app pages within the Windows Store, and unable to load feedback in the feedback hub. I can access all of these fine whilst not on the VPN.

Does anyone know what the endpoints for either of these apps are, so I can look to add exceptions to our web filtering service and firewall, to allow me to access these whilst on our VPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue seemed to end up being related to the VPN generally (forced tunneling), rather than our corporate web filtering.

It was resolved by stumbling upon this Microsoft doc and explanation of the issue and resolution (network isolation/boundaries): [MS Doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/microsoft-store-not-open-domain-joine-computer-vpn)